# Transfer EventID from 1 file to another file

Tags: php, sql, edit

Currently I am making an event calendar something I want the user to edit there event:

EXAMPLE:

events.php
http://i42.tinypic.com/sgsvth.png

The edit button action goes to edit.php

edit.php
http://i41.tinypic.com/2wrl26s.png

How can I include EventID from events.php into edit.php so I can UPDATE the appropriate event.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` values in the URL.

```
edit.php?event_id=4
```

Retrieve the value like so:

```
$id = $_GET['event_id'];
```